# Running shinyApp in shiny Server

Tags: r, shiny, data-science, shiny-server

I am trying to run my shiny application on shiny Server.
At this point I cannot understand the way that shiny server works, I mean I have two R scripts, the ui.R and the server.R inside the shiny server I have this vector. Please refer the code below

```
#server.R

v_outcome <-  c("Confirmados", "Hospitalizados", "Intubado", 
                "Muertes", "Pruebas", "Síntomas", "UCI")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # DASHBOARD PAGE ----------------------------------------------------------
  
  #Confirmados 
  output$confirmados <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      #paste0(25 + input$count, "%"), "Confirmados", icon = icon("list"),
      #color = "purple",
      paste0(confirmedNacional),
      subtitle = "Confirmados",
      icon = icon("fas fa-plus-square"),
      color    = "yellow", 
    )
  })
```

This is just a small chunk of my script what I don´t understand is why when I run server.R the script cannot read the vector in the first line, even I tried to add the vector inside the function server but is not working. Which is the way that I need to append my vector?

Thank you

Comment: `paste0(confirmedNacional)` should be `paste0(v_outcome)`?

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, this page was very useful https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

This was my solution:

I created a file called global.R inside this file I declared all the vectors that my UI and my server use.